# Asyncio google search in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I apologize if the question is too basic given that I'm still learning async programming in general.
I want to perform a Google search to list of companies using Python. Because there are over 20,000 companies in the list, I would like to perform those asynchronously. I tried doing this using the asyncio library in Python but I'm not able to get it to work, it still runs synchronously and for over 4hs.
How can I make the code below run asynchronously?

When I run this:

```
from googlesearch import search
import asyncio

companies = [
  'Apple',
  'Google',
  'Tesla'
]

async def gsearch(company):
  return search(company, num=3, stop=3)

async def make_gsearch(company):
  print(f"Searching {company}")
  search_res = await gsearch(company)
  print(f"Done with {company}")
  return list(search_res)

async def run_search():
  return await asyncio.gather(*[make_gsearch(company) for company in companies])
  
asyncio.run(run_search())
```

I get this output:

```
Searching Apple
Done with Apple
Searching Google
Done with Google
Searching Tesla
Done with Tesla
```

But I would like to get it to start each search while it waits for the other search results to come back. This would yield something like:

```
Searching Apple
Searching Google
Searching Tesla
Done with Apple
Done with Google
Done with Tesla
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered multithreading? It's easier (IMHO) and entirely appropriate for your needs

Comment: The problem is that `sesrch` is still a blocking call. You’ll either need to switch to something asyncio-aware or use concurrent.futures as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have 20 thousand companies, is it ok to start 20 thousand threads to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggested multithreading in the comment section. Here's an example of how you could approach this:

```
from googlesearch import search
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

companies = [
  'Apple',
  'Google',
  'Tesla'
]

def gsearch(company):
    return search(company, num_results=3)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for future in [executor.submit(gsearch, company) for company in companies]:
            print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.apple.com/uk/', 'https://www.apple.com/uk/', '/search?q=Apple&num=4&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=-TtEc9M5pE7LPM%252CobY4_sHHUHwJ8M%252C%252Fm%252F0k8z&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQBxGosm-inv0sd7rMvgQiQEXKyzw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ1cC9oev0AhWT8OAKHYa4Bc4Q_B16BAgVEAI#imgrc=-TtEc9M5pE7LPM']
['https://www.google.co.uk/', 'https://www.google.co.uk/', 'https://twitter.com/Google?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor', '/search?q=Google&num=4&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=mM5eejaz-bUIsM%252C0UCf55-GTy6fDM%252C%252Fm%252F045c7b&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kS3fhB6I4-4YGkbI-0POxk60cjoEw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk1MC9oev0AhWKsBQKHcNXATsQ_B16BAgnEAI#imgrc=mM5eejaz-bUIsM']
['https://www.tesla.com/en_gb', 'https://www.tesla.com/en_gb', '/search?q=Tesla&num=4&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=TJ5IFimoIu4OzM%252Cahl5uU9rAQNcyM%252C%252Fm%252F0dr90d&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kS3EuOF372E5qoJG2eO01XrJehNdA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip3sC9oev0AhWG2hQKHavHCzwQ_B16BAgmEAI#imgrc=TJ5IFimoIu4OzM']
```

**Update:**

I increased the number of companies to 20 (all unique and real companies). The total duration for execution (including print) is less than 2 seconds

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm a bit worried about starting 20 thousand threads to do go over the full list, not sure if this is safe, would you recommend that? Also, I need to store all results in a list of some sort, do I need to use a lock for the threads when appending to the final list? Thanks again!

Comment: You are very unlikely to have that many concurrent threads. That's the point about the thread pool - there will only be as many as your system can reasonably cope with. It's perfectly safe. As you're using threads (as opposed to subprocesses) remember that Python dictionaries and lists are thread safe. That means that each thread can add data reliably to some global object

Comment: Of course, you can always apply limits by specifying max_workers to the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor

Comment: UPDATE: If you're going to try using googlesearch for 20,000 companies you are **HIGHLY LIKELY** to start getting HTTP 429 errors. Google will not love you any more ;-)